# vtable information gdb vs readelf/objdump

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, vtable

Using in gdb (e.g. for *this* pointing to some MyClass instance)

> info vtbl this

on linux sometimes shows a high address somewhere below 0x800000000000.
But asking

> readelf --symbols --wide /usr/bin/my-binary|c++filt|grep "vtable.*MyClass"

shows a different - very much lower - value.
I guess this is due to code relocation.
How can i correlate these values?
Where is "documented" which sections/area are relocated?

I am asking because if have a dangling instance, with memory area already re-used for some other object. As a consequence my this ptr has a "wrong" vtable entry.
How can i find out, which class the vtable is now referencing to?


Exercising with a **simple** (small) test program does **not** have this problem:

```
frank@frank-PC:~/TEST$ cat test.cpp

#include <iostream>

class Base 
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
    }

    virtual void DoIt(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Base::DoIt()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void DoIt(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::DoIt()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main(
    int,
    char**)
{
    Derived d;
    d.DoIt();
    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -fPIC -o test -g3 test.cpp
```

gdb:

```
frank@frank-PC:~/TEST$ gdb --batch -ex "break 22" -ex "r" -ex "info vtbl this" ./test

warning: /home/frank/.gdbinit: Success
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400c13: file test.cpp, line 22.
Derived::DoIt()

Breakpoint 1, Derived::DoIt (this=0x7fffffffdad0) at test.cpp:22
22      }
vtable for 'Derived' @ 0x601d88 (subobject @ 0x7fffffffdad0):
[0]: 0x400c62 <Derived::~Derived()>
[1]: 0x400ca4 <Derived::~Derived()>
[2]: 0x400bdc <Derived::DoIt()>
```

symbol from readelf:

```
frank@frank-PC:~/TEST$ readelf --symbols --wide ./test|c++filt |grep vtable
    11: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info@CXXABI_1.3 (4)
    13: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info@CXXABI_1.3 (4)
    85: 0000000000601d78    40 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   23 vtable for Derived
    86: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info@@CXXABI_1.3
    97: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info@@CXXABI_1.3
   104: 0000000000601da0    40 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   23 vtable for Base
```

So vtable for Derived is at 0x0000000000601d78.

sections from readelf:

```
frank@frank-PC:~/TEST$ readelf --sections --wide ./test
There are 40 section headers, starting at offset 0x11a38:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000400238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000400254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000400274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000400298 000298 00001c 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000000004002b8 0002b8 0001c8 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000400480 000480 00021e 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          000000000040069e 00069e 000026 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         00000000004006c8 0006c8 000080 00   A  6   3  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000400748 000748 0000a8 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            00000000004007f0 0007f0 0000c0 18  AI  5  26  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        00000000004008b0 0008b0 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        00000000004008d0 0008d0 000090 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        0000000000400960 000960 000008 00  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000400970 000970 0003d2 00  AX  0   0 16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000400d44 000d44 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000400d50 000d50 000037 00   A  0   0  8
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        0000000000400d88 000d88 000084 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        0000000000400e10 000e10 00025c 00   A  0   0  8
  [19] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        000000000040106c 00106c 00000c 00   A  0   0  1
  [20] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000601d58 001d58 000010 00  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000601d68 001d68 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [22] .jcr              PROGBITS        0000000000601d70 001d70 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        0000000000601d78 001d78 000078 00  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000601df0 001df0 0001f0 10  WA  6   0  8
  [25] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000601fe0 001fe0 000020 08  WA  0   0  8
  [26] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000602000 002000 000058 08  WA  0   0  8
  [27] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000602058 002058 000018 00  WA  0   0  8
  [28] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000602070 002070 000008 00  WA  0   0  1
  [29] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 002070 000034 01  MS  0   0  1
  [30] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0020a4 0000b0 00      0   0  1
  [31] .debug_info       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 002154 001925 00      0   0  1
  [32] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003a79 000516 00      0   0  1
  [33] .debug_line       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003f8f 00080f 00      0   0  1
  [34] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 00479e 009ba4 01  MS  0   0  1
  [35] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 00e342 0000a0 00      0   0  1
  [36] .debug_macro      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 00e3e2 00251e 00      0   0  1
  [37] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0118ac 000186 00      0   0  1
  [38] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 010900 000a50 18     39  59  8
  [39] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 011350 00055c 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

So relevant section is .data.rel.ro

objdump:

```
frank@frank-PC:~/TEST$ objdump -s -j .data.rel.ro ./test

./test:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .data.rel.ro:
 601d78 00000000 00000000 c81d6000 00000000  ..........`.....
 601d88 620c4000 00000000 a40c4000 00000000  b.@.......@.....
 601d98 dc0b4000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..@.............
 601da8 e01d6000 00000000 460b4000 00000000  ..`.....F.@.....
 601db8 7c0b4000 00000000 a20b4000 00000000  |.@.......@.....
 601dc8 00000000 00000000 780d4000 00000000  ........x.@.....
 601dd8 e01d6000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..`.............
 601de8 810d4000 00000000                    ..@.....
```

**Note**
There is an offset of 0x10 (#16) between the "vtable for Derived" information of readelf (0x0000000000601d78) and gdb (0x0000000000601d88).
The reason for that is described here: https://www.rpi.edu/dept/cis/software/g77-mingw32/info-html/g++int.html#Vtables, chapter "Specification of thunked vtables".

"For vtable thunks, each slot only consists of a pointer to the virtual function, which might be a thunk function. The **first slot** in the vtable is an offset of the this pointer to the complete object, which is needed as a parameter to __dynamic_cast. The **second slot** is the virtual typeinfo function. All other slots are allocated with the same procedure as in the non-thunked case. Allocation of vfields also uses the same procedure as described above."

Looking again at those leading #16 octets in my example we have

```
601d78 00000000 00000000 c81d6000 00000000  ..........`.....
```

**1st slot**  0x0000000000000000
**2nd slot**  0x0000000000601dc8 (octets re-ordered for a valid address)

Cross-check for **2nd slot**:

```
> objdump -z -D -j .data.rel.ro test|c++filt

0000000000601dc8 <typeinfo for Derived>:
  601dc8:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  601dca:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  601dcc:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  601dce:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  601dd0:       78 0d                   js     601ddf <typeinfo for Derived+0x17>
  601dd2:       40 00 00                add    %al,(%rax)
  601dd5:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  601dd7:       00 e0                   add    %ah,%al
  601dd9:       1d 60 00 00 00          sbb    $0x60,%eax
  601dde:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
```

Comment: It helps to show *actual* commands you are using. No version of GDB that I can find knows anything about `info vtable` (they do recognize `info vtbl` though).

Comment: Did you compile with `-fPIC` or `-fPIE`? In this case, all sections from your binary will relocated at each launch.

Comment: Hi Jezz, yes, when i use -fPIC i get the stuff in .data.rel.ro instead of .rodata. But at least it's there. But not for the *real* executable i am looking into

Comment: Sounds like Address Space Layout Randomization at work.